# How do I use git flow with a staging environment?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-flow

We are using git-flow to handle hotfixes & features, with a develop branch & the master branch (for production).

What is the easiest way to add a staging branch to the mix so that we can validate work that is on its way to production from develop while still keeping the helpfulness of git-flow?

Answer (score 16):

I would say that staging should be based on a git flow release branch. After a `git flow release start` and `git flow release publish` you can start QA work on that branch, including deploying it to a staging area. When the QA work in the staging area has proven the code ready for production deploy in production and do `git flow release finish`.

If you are using TeamCity, you can easily set up the server to detect new remote release branches and automatically set up builds for them, [see here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Working+with+Feature+Branches).

Comment: You suggest using a different branch for each potential release rather than having a dedicated branch to "the next release in testing" (staging) just like there is always a develop & master branch?

Comment: Yes, that would be the standard git-flow way of doing it, afaik. You could always name the branch the same, e.g. "staging". But normal use of git-flow would remove the branch when you `git flow release finish` and recreate it when you `git flow release start`

Answer (score 5):

I've just started to use git flow but IMHO the easiest way is to set *next release* as `dev` branch and *production releases* as `stage` branch and then e.g.: manually merge with `master` branch (your real production).

In case you release version 1.2.0 to `stage` and then find bugs in your release (4 hotfixes e.g.: in core CMS, feature1, feature3 and feature4) then you can always apply patches so for instance you can end up with version 1.2.4 and then finally merge it to production.

UPDATE: This scenario assumes that you do not have a roll-back mechanism so you are always *adding* commits to fix, release feature or anything else. If you do have a roll-back mechanism then you don't need to worry about your bugs in your production. Just when you discover error use roll-back to set-up  previous working version. E.g: if you find bug in version `1.2.3` go back to version `1.2.2`. Fix bug, test on `dev` then on `stage` and push to production as version `1.2.4`. So your production will jump from `1.2.2` straight to `1.2.4`.